# Is assoc just syntax sugar for find?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

```
CL-USER> *mylist*
((RED . 5) (RED . 4) (RED . 3) (BLUE . 5) (RED . 2) (BLUE . 4))
CL-USER> (assoc 'blue *mylist*)
(BLUE . 5)
CL-USER> (find 'blue *mylist* :key #'car)
(BLUE . 5)
```

It would seem to me that `assoc` is just a particular case of `find`, is this true or am I missing some extra functionality from `assoc` that is not apparent here?

Comment: In a [recent MSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437), someone asked, "I have a question about python naming conventions. The answer is readily available on the Python documentation, but I think it would make for a great Stack Overflow question. Is it ok to still ask it?"  The answer to this question, as [Lars Brinkhoff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20140179/1281433) shows, it actually _in_ the documentation for `assoc`. One of the answers to the MSO question said, "if the question doesn't really add anything that exceeds the current documentation, don't ask it."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it is specifically answered in the documentation page for `assoc`.  (See [What should one do if they have a question that the answer is already on google?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208372/225437).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_assocc.htm):

> The two expressions
>
> ```
> (assoc item list :test fn)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> (find item list :test fn :key #'car)
> ```
>
> are equivalent in meaning with one exception: if nil appears in alist in place of a pair, and item is nil, find will compute the car of the nil in alist, find that it is equal to item, and return nil, whereas assoc will ignore the nil in alist and continue to search for an actual cons whose car is nil.